# Sinatra Modular Application not working

Tags: ruby, sinatra, modular

I am new to Sinatra, and am learning it by following the README file. My ultimate goal is to create a modular application as described on the [Sinatra Serving Modular Application](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Serving%20a%20Modular%20Application) page. Unfortunately, my application doesn't work - if I use `config.ru` it generates an error:

> ```
> uninitialized constant Object::MyClass (NameError)
> ```

and modifying the code to do:

```
run! if app_file == $0
```

is not working as well. Below is my code:

my_app.rb:

```
require 'sinatra/base'
class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
    get '/' do  
            test  
    end  
    def test  
            return "Hello World!"  
    end  
end
```

config.ru:

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__)+'/my_app'  
run Myapp.new
```

The commands `ruby config.ru` and `rackup -p 4567` are not working - I receive (`NameError`), as I mentioned before. Does anyone have any ideas? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I should not be so silly to post a problem which is a typo error.
:(
**Sorry guys.**

> run MyApp.new

Answer (score 1):

I have wrote a simple tutorial about this topic.

(no ads)3
http://codex.heroku.com/past/2011/2/15/sinatrabase_in_the_modulnd/